# How to iterate over @Query() object in Nest js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

Is there any way, how to iterate over object which we got in controller by `@Query()` anotations?

We have dynamic count and name of query parameters in GET, so we need to take whole `@Query()` object and iterate over them to know what paramas we exactly have.

But if I want to iterate over that object I got error that object is not iterable.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get an array of the keys of the query object. You can then iterate over this array of keys:

```
@Get()
getHello(@Query() query) {
  for (const queryKey of Object.keys(query)) {
    console.log(`${queryKey}: ${query[queryKey]}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also use `Object.entries` - `for (const [queryKey, queryValue] of Object.entries(query)) {}`.

Answer (score 3):

In nest controller, use `@Query()` / `@Body()` / 
`@Headers()` decorator without argument 
will return a key-value javascript object.

for example:

```
    // request url: http://example.com/path-foo/path-bar?qf=1&qb=2

    @Post(':foo/:bar')
    async function baz(@Query() query,@Param() param) {
        const keys = Object.keys(query); // ['qf', 'qb']
        const vals = Object.values(query); // ['1', '2']
        const pairs = Object.entries(query); // [['qf','1'],['qb','2']]
        const params = Object.entries(param); // [['foo','path-foo'],['bar','path-bar']]
        // these are all iterate able array
        // so you can use any Array's built-in function
        // e.g. for / forEach / map / filter ...
    }
```

reference:

[Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
    // sample object
    const obj = {
      foo: 'this is foo',
      bar: 'this is bar',
      baz: 'this is baz',
    };

    Object.keys(obj);
    Object.values(obj);
    Object.entries(obj);

    /**
     * return iterable array:
     *
     * ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
     *
     * ['this is foo', 'this is bar', 'this is baz']
     *
     * [
     *     ['foo', 'this is foo']
     *     ['bar', 'this is bar']
     *     ['baz', 'this is baz']
     * ]
     */
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your answer.