# How to expand @Query() dto with unknown properties?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I did build an table with pagination loading like [in this tutorial](https://pietrzakadrian.com/blog/how-to-create-pagination-in-nestjs-with-typeorm-swagger). I currently have `@Query() pageOptionsDto: PageOptionsDto<PlayerSortColumn>` as parameter in my `get` controller function.

This is my PageOptionsDto:

```
export class PageOptionsDto<T> {
  @ApiPropertyOptional({ enum: Order, default: Order.ASC })
  @IsEnum(Order)
  @IsOptional()
  readonly order?: Order = Order.ASC;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  readonly orderColumn?: T;

  @ApiPropertyOptional({
    minimum: 1,
    default: 1,
  })
  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsInt()
  @Min(1)
  @IsOptional()
  readonly page?: number = 1;

  @ApiPropertyOptional({
    minimum: 1,
    maximum: 50,
    default: 10,
  })
  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsInt()
  @Min(1)
  @Max(50)
  @IsOptional()
  readonly take?: number = 10;

  get skip(): number {
    return (this.page - 1) * this.take;
  }
}
```

I want to expand this with filters since each column of my table has it's own filter. On the frontend I already have an object that contains every currently set filter like `{name: 'ni', age: '20'}` as example if the filter for the `name` column contains `ni` and the filter for the `age` column contains `20`.

Now my question: How can I pass this information to my backend? I don't want to hardcode all column names into the `PageOptionsDto` since I use this class for all my tables.

I could add those filters to the request url, example: `https://localhost:8080/player/table?page=2&take=10&order=DESC&orderColumn=life&name=ni&age=20` and the [read them back out from the query object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048217/how-to-iterate-over-query-object-in-nest-js) but how should the `PageOptionsDto<T>` look like because `name` and `age` is not defined in this class and I don't want to use `any` as query type.

Another option would be to just change it to `post` and send this filter information as body but since I already use query params I wanted to solve it with them to.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is using Mapped Types https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types#intersection. The approach saves swagger decorators from the base entity.
You can create a separate DTO that combines pagination options and the base entity. I would suggest to store the new DTO near the base entity.

Example of the code:

```
class MyEntityDto {
  @IsString()
  @ApiProperty()
  name: string

  @IsNumber()
  @ApiProperty()
  age: number;
}

class PaginatedMyEntityDto extends IntersectionType(PageOptionsDto<MyEntityDto>, MyEntityDto) {}

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(@Query() q: PaginatedMyEntityDto): string {
    q.name
    q.age
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably solve this by adding a property to you dto that is a plain object (or record if you will). For example, you could do

```
class TestDto
{
    @IsObject()
    @IsOptional()
    public obj?: object;
}
```

Then, in your request do something like this: `localhost:4000?obj[test]=value`